# Is there a way to change to black the login screen on macOS Ventura?

Tags: mac, ventura

When I turn my mac on, I see the list of users against a colorful ventura background.

I hate that background because it is difficult to see the mouse pointer. I want to change it to black.

I am not talking about the lock screen. I am talking about the login screen, where you see all users.

Is there a way to remove that background image with an all black one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS will change the background of the login window to match the background of a user account but only AFTER you have selected that user account and when the login window is set to display “List of users.”

There is no documented means to change the background when the login window is set to show “Name and password.”

Comment: I was suspecting that. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP's actual complaint was that they had difficulty seeing the mouse pointer on the colorful Ventura select-user-to-log-in screen, I wonder if they are aware that the pointer graphic can be made temporarily much larger to help locate it by "shaking" the mouse back and forth rapidly for a couple seconds.  (Assuming that that feature is switched on in 'System Settings—>Accessibility—>Display—>Shake mouse pointer to locate'.)  Just sayin'...

Comment: This is not answering the question asked. You could add that as a comment once you get sufficient reputation.